# mayavi hangs under enthought canopy

Tags: canopy, mayavi

I have been using Mayavi under enthought Canopy successfully for past 8 months. During a recent update using egg, I got a message about a missing egg in the Canopy package manager and found Mayavi Hanging. I tried to revet to older Mayavi (4.0.0) but no luck. It only works if I revert to Mayavi 3.4 version. 
Can somebody suggest me possible sources of error. I am using Windows 8  64bit. Running Mayavi2.exe, Mayavi-script2.py and importing mayavi - none of these work under Mayavi version 4.0.0 onwards. ( On a 32 bit machine, however, I have no problems)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you reset your Canopy User Python environment to start clean:

In the Canopy GUI, `print sys.prefix` to see where that environment's directory is, then quit Canopy and delete that directory (e.g. in Windows Explorer). Restart Canopy, and your environment will be auto-recreated from the installation-time eggs. (For that reason, you might want to first take the time to uninstall your Canopy, and install the current Canopy 1.5.1 from https://store.enthought.com/downloads/ but that's secondary) -- in-app auto-updates are currently disabled, and will be for at least a few more weeks.

Then open a Canopy Command Prompt (from the Start Menu or from the Canopy Tools menu) and type
`enpkg mayavi` to update to the current mayavi.

If you are non-academic free user, you'll need to wait a few days before this will work, as Mayavi is not currently accessible to such users using enpkg. Sorry for that inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling and re-installing Mayavi a couple of times, I continued to have the same problem that Mayavi used to hang.

I have managed to solve it by deleting a file 
C:\Users\SUK000???\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\mayavi_e3\pyface\workbench\wx\windows_memento

It seems that Mayavi creates this file by default if it does not exist. If it exists, it tries to use the settings in this file to open Mayavi interface and hangs if it does not like the settings.

That was a relief. Thanks for your ideas.